# Power BI - Copy Paste Row-level security between PIBX files

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, row-level-security

As said in the title, I would like to **copy paste the RLS** done in the **PIBX A** to the **PIBX B.**

I have done much research on google and I found out a solution **using the template** but these 2 PIBX has been developed so I can not generate a template from A to start the development of B

I tried the **Tabular Editor** integrated in Power BI as External Tool too but when I do copy paste, it says that the Role TEST1_PRIX5 (from PIBX A to copy) points to the table which doesn't exist. The table 'Feuil1' exists in both PIBX
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxci1.png)

I found this one here https://exceleratorbi.com.au/copy-measures-between-2-power-bi-files/. It shows how to copy paste measures and I try to do the same with RLS.  The first step is to stick the option :  "*Store datasets using enhanced metadata format*". I don't have this option in my PWBI Desktop, do you think the problem is here ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: which parts of rls do you want to copy? the roles?

Comment: Hello jon 
Exactly. Manage Roles

Comment: No you can't copy these over. You can save file 'A' as file 'B' and remove any objects tables you don't need.

Comment: A and B have already been developed, including differents KPI but have same data. That's why I can not remove any objects. Do you know another way to copy paste roles smartly from A to B Jon ? Thank you for your time

Comment: TabularEditor support also c# scripting. Propably you can write script. Using some of thers properties to get all modelRole and RLS, save it to file and then load to different model https://github.com/otykier/TabularEditor/wiki/TabularEditor.TOMWrapper#modelrole

Answer (score 0):

In Tabular Editor you have to enable experimental Power BI features in "File > Preferences" to be able to copy the roles without this error:

[image: File > Preferences > Features > Allow unsupported Power BI features (experimental)]

Make sure you save the changes back to the .pbix file and double check in "Manage Roles" in Power BI whether or not the roles came in. It worked for me this way.